# R: using ggplot2 with a group_by data set

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I can't quite figure this out. A CSV of 200+ rows assigned to `data` like so:

```
gid,bh,p1_id,p1_x,p1_y
90467,R,543333,80.184,98.824
90467,L,408045,74.086,90.923
90467,R,543333,57.629,103.797
90467,L,408045,58.589,95.937
```

Trying to group by `p1_id` and plot the mean values for `p1_x` and `p1_y`:

```
grp <- data %>% group_by(p1_id)
```

Trying to plot geom_point objects like so:

```
geom_point(aes(mean(grp$p1_x), mean(grp$p1_y), color=grp$p1_id))
```

But that isn't showing unique plot points per distinct `p1_id` values.

What's the missing step here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not calculate the mean first?

```
library(dplyr)
grp <- data %>% 
        group_by(p1_id) %>%
        summarise(mean_p1x = mean(p1_x),
                  mean_p1y = mean(p1_y))
```

Then plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(grp, aes(x = mean_p1x, y = mean_p1y)) +
        geom_point(aes(color = as.factor(p1_id)))
```

[image]

**Edit:** As per @eipi10, you can also pipe directly into `ggplot`

```
data %>% 
        group_by(p1_id) %>%
        summarise(mean_p1x = mean(p1_x),
                  mean_p1y = mean(p1_y)) %>%
        ggplot(aes(x = mean_p1x, y = mean_p1y)) +
        geom_point(aes(color = as.factor(p1_id)))
```

Comment: You can also pipe the summarized data directly into ggplot without saving it as a separate object first.

Comment: How can one revise this so the color legend treats the integer values as discrete values and not a scale? They are identifiers, not values.

Comment: @Wells Change the aesthetic to `color = as.factor(p1_id)`. See the updated answer